# Generics with a common method

Tags: dart, flutter

I was trying to write an abstract `JsonSerializable` class in order to have something like this:

```
abstract class JsonSerializable<T>{
    T fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> map);
    Map<String,dynamic> toMap();
    T fromJsonString(String jsonString){
        return fromMap(json.decode(jsonString));
    }
    String toJsonString(){
        return json.encode(toMap());
    }
}
```

My first problem was that `fromMap` and `fromJsonString` cannot be used as constructors, so I figured that could do something like this:

```
class Foo extends JsonSerializable<Foo>{

  Foo();
  factory Foo.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> map){
    return fromMap(map);  
  }

  @override
  Foo fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    // TODO: implement fromMap
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    // TODO: implement toMap
    return null;
  }
}
```

Now, the code above causes the Dart analyzer to complain since I'm trying to access an instance method form a factory constructor.

So I thought I could just implement those methods without inheriting and overriding them (I know, it's a dirty solution), but still this won't provide me something that could just tell "hey this kind of class has this method".

Am I completely missing the point in this? 

Is there a clean solution which does not involve code generation plugins, which apparently do not support generics?

My API responses have all this structure:

```
{
    "key1":"value1",
    "otherStuffKey":["blah", "blah"],
    "data": <the object I want to generalize>
}
```

I need generics because I'd like to parse the object serialized as `data` value into different classes which have the same behavior.

**PS:** The `toMap` and `toJsonString` methods are useless if I'm going to parse the response, but they would be pretty useful to complete the circle and allow the use of this `JsonSerializable` for serializing requests too.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: oh yeah I know, in fact that's one of my problems